# jquery and jScrollPane and ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I am building a site that has a fair bit of ajax on it and I seem to have hit a bit of a roadblock with getting jScrollPane to work for me.

This might be hard to write down.

I have a main page and at the base of it I have a div which I use to write all my overlays or 'lightbxes' to. e.g.

```
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#popup').load('some-url.php');return false;">content etc</a>
<div id="popup"></div>
</body>
```

Then in one such overlay (some-url.php) I have more content and then again I have some more divs which get populated using ajax.

some-url.php

```
<body>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<script>
$('#left').load('another-url.php');
</script>
</body>
```

Now lets say div id="left" I want a jScrollPane scroller on it, but it's content loads via ajax.

What I have tried is in 'another-url.php' loading up all my content and then trying to add the scrollpane.

'another-url.php'

```
<div class="wrapper>
// iterate through my DB and gets lots of content
</div>
<script>
$('#left').jScrollPane();
</script>
```

This fails, it says that $('#left').jScrollPane(); is not a function, so I tried putting it in the first overlay after I load up the div with content.

```
<body>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<script>
$('#left').load('another-url.php');
$('#left').jScrollPane();
</script>
</body>
```

This doesn't fail the first time, though I get no scroller... but if I reload it again it fails again saying that $('#left').jScrollPane(); is not a function.

So I looked at the docs and tried using the dynamic content example.

```
<body>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<script>
var api = $('#left').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
('a.some-link').bind(
'click',
function(){
api.getContentPane.load(
'another-url.php',
function(){
api.reinitialise();
}
);
}
);
</script>
</body>
```

But this time it again says that $('#left').jScrollPane(); is not a function.Also when I get one of these errors, the other jScrollPane on the site that is not ajax'd suddenly stops working also, until I reload the page so obviously jScrollPane is getting the shits with me somehow...

Am hoping the guy that created the library might hang out here and respond.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set jScrollPane() to fire after the contents are loaded. If i'm not mistaken, the load method is ascynchronous and your `jscrollpane()` will fire before contents are loaded to html dome `$("#left")`. Which means that it really isn't available when jscrollpane fired. try to use the `$.ajaxSetup({ascync:false});` and see if that will help. You might have to use a `$.get` method if the `$.ajaxSetup` doesn't work for the load method.

IE:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$('#left').load('another-url.php');
$('#left').jScrollPane();
```

if ajaxSetup don't work with the load method try to use the .get method

```
 $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    var $jqxhr = $.get('another-url.php');
    $jqxhr.success(function(responseText,statusText,jqxhr){
      $('#left').html(responseText);
    });
    $jqxhr.complete(function(){
      $('#left').jScrollPane();
    });
    $jqxhr.error(function(){alert("error loading content");});
```

Hope it helps. Worked for me. I had a similar problem.